# Accidentally Delete the server farm from SharePoint Central Admin - SBS 2011

Tags: central-administration

I cannot access anymore the Central Admin page and I encounter error using configuration wizard. how can i create new farm or restore my backup farms?

What should i do?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What kind of backups do you have in place now?

Answer (score 1):

If creating a new SPFarm is one of your options, try do the following:

Trying to run "SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard" when SharePoint server already is installed will not act the same as running it for the first time, but you can still force the wizard to run a clean installation of an SPFarm by deleting the "dns" registry located here:
Start --> Run --> regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB

This will make the wizard act as if it's running for the first time and create a new Content_DB. Turn to the logs if you still get error running the wizard.

Thanks and I hope I could help :-)